# Smarty HTML Escape doesnt work

Tags: php, smarty

I try to escape the variable output to escape HTML in an XML Export. I dont know what i'm doing wrong. The Export is used in xt:commerce 5 online shop.

Smarty should be v. 3.1

**Template**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<orders>
    {assign var=foo value='<b>baaa& ü ä ß ö <> aaa</b>'}{$foo|escape:'htmlall'}
</orders>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<orders>
    <b>baaa& ü ä ß ö <> aaa</b>
</orders>
```

Answer (score 0):

Escaping html makes sure your browser does not use the content as html, for example if you remove the escape then the text will be bold.
To actually remove the tags from the string, you must use strip_tags (https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.strip.tags.tpl):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<orders>
    {assign var=foo value='<b>baaa& ü ä ß ö <> aaa</b>'}{$foo|strip_tags:}
</orders>
```

Output:

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?="">
<orders>
     baaa&amp; ü ä ß ö   aaa 
</orders>
```

Comment: As you can see in my Output, there is no escaping although i used the escape function, so the html should be escaped to:

    &lt;b&gt;baaa&amp; &uuml; &auml; &szlig; &ouml; &lt;&gt; aaa&lt;/b&gt;

Comment: That is not what escaping means in this context, the escaping here meaning your browser won't actually show the result as bold but shows the result as plain text

Comment: To actually remove the elements from the string you need to filter them out

Comment: I don't want to remove the element, the should be displayed in plain text. 
`<b>` should be displayed as `&lt;b&gt;` in html source code for example.

Answer (score 0):

to escape an html tag  in smarty you should use strip_tags

{$subcategory.description|strip_tags}